# getaddrinfo(3) failed

Tags: php, curl, getaddrinfo

I'm trying to connect to a webservice using a PHP wrapper (which is using curl under the covers).

On my local linux machine running PHP 5.3 it works perfectly. However, when I move to a remote server (also running PHP 5.3 on Linux) the call the the webservice URL returns:

```
getaddrinfo(3) failed for http://server.host.com:8080/login
```

But when I issue a curl request from the command line, it returns the expected URL.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `dig example.com` return when run on the remote host?

Comment: What format is `<URL>` in - is it just the hostname, or a URL with `http://` and/or anything after the hostname like a port number or trailing slash?

Comment: @Ladadadada: 
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61127
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.   IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.  62043 IN A 192.0.43.10

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.  62043 IN NS a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.  62043 IN NS b.iana-servers.net.

Comment: It's the same reason you can't mail a package to a phone number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's expected. The `ping` command accepts either an IP address or a hostname and not a URL. Same goes for getaddrinfo() and getnameinfo() functions.

curl works because it is supposed to work with URLs.

Comment: I've removed the ping statement in the question, since as you point out it doesn't have anything to do with curl failing. Thanks